# Context.User doesn't persist between page requests in MVC - best approach?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, httpcontext

Excuse me if this has been asked already on SO I've looked around the forums and can't find the specific answer. I am developing an intranet site and I am setting a GenericPrincipal to Context.User. This takes place in the Global.asax before the default controller loads. The controller uses a custom authorize attribute to manage which users can see what content.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Optimization;
using System.Web.Routing;
using System.Security.Principal;

namespace IntranetTest
{
    // Note: For instructions on enabling IIS6 or IIS7 classic mode, 
    // visit http://go.microsoft.com/?LinkId=9394801

    public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {
        protected void Application_Start()
        {
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

            WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
            FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
            BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);

            DAL.IME_IMechEHubUsers IME_IMechEHubUsers = new DAL.IME_IMechEHubUsers();
            List<string> Roles = IME_IMechEHubUsers.GetRoles();
            Models.User User = IME_IMechEHubUsers.GetUser();

            GenericPrincipal userPrincipal = new GenericPrincipal(new GenericIdentity(User.RoleName), Roles.ToArray());

            Context.User = userPrincipal;
        }
    }
}
```

My problem is when I make a second GET request by clicking on one of the links on the page it no longer knows the role of user. It has been overridden by the users network identity.

[image]

[image]

I am a bit stuck with how to authorize users in an intranet application. The database used to store the roles and the users is the aspnet membership tables. But they are just standard tables and the question is more how to persist a users role between requests using httpcontext.user.

Comment: do you have a domain? can you use windows auth?

Comment: @DanielA.White Yes it's the corporate network and the auth is happening when the user logs into Windows. The details are from AD. I want to enforce roles using authorization.

Comment: asp.net has this built in: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647405.aspx

Comment: You should not be doing any type of authentication/authorization in the application_start method.  You should let your Authentication scheme handle it automatically per request.

Comment: @ErikPhilips Ok, the reason I put it there was I was using the authorize attribute for the controller and I didn't know where I set the role of the user. So I put the code in the global.asax and it sets the role before hitting the controller. I should add I don't have control over AD.

Comment: @nickgowdy You have an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/171858), you've presented us a solution that does not work to a problem you have not described.  Please realize we need to know what you are trying to accomplish.  For example you might say, *I am trying to not use any built-in authentication scheme because I want all my users to use the same authentication*. Secondarily, *how to persist a users role between requests using httpcontext.user* is handled automatically by asp.net using all supported authentication frameworks.